# ng-class strange behaviour after after $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I have made following directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.widgets')
        .directive('zzForminput', formInput);

    function formInput($compile) {
        // Usage:
        //     <div zz-forminput></div>

        function setupDom(element) {
            var input = element.querySelector("input, textarea, select");
            var type = input.getAttribute("type");
            var name = input.getAttribute("name");
            if (type !== "checkbox" && type !== "radio") {
                input.classList.add("form-control");
            }
            var label = element.querySelector("label");
            label.classList.add("control-label");

            element.classList.add("form-group");
            return name;
        }

        function addNgClass(form, element, name, $compile, scope) {
            var isExistingNgClass = element[0].attributes["data-ng-class"] || element[0].attributes["ng-class"];
            if (!isExistingNgClass) {
                var ngClass = "{'has-error':" + form.$name + "." + name + ".$invalid && " +
                                "(" + form.$name + "." + name + ".$dirty || vm.submit), " +
                                "'has-success':" + form.$name + "." + name + ".$valid && " +
                                form.$name + "." + name + ".$dirty}";
                element.attr("data-ng-class", ngClass);
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        }

        function link($compile) {
            return function (scope, element, attrs, form) {
                var name = setupDom(element[0]);

                addNgClass(form, element, name, $compile, scope);
            }
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^form',
            link: link($compile)
        }
    }

}());
```

I am using the directive as:

```
<div zz-forminput>
   <label for="firstName" class="col-md-4">First Name*</label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
       <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" data-ng-model="vm.userDetails.firstName" required data-ng-maxlength="100">
   </div>
</div>
```

Angular compiles the markup successfully. When I enter any text in input field, has-success is not added to div. But when I clear the textbox, has-success class is appied to the div. Now, when I enter some text in input, has-success is applied to the div.

Please provide me a solution to this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this weird behavior is because of how you handle contents of the element that hosts your directive.

What happens is that the contents, including the `ng-model` directive on the input, are compiled twice: once when Angular goes over the DOM (in the compile phase), and once when you manually invoke the `$compile` service (in the linking phase of your directive). This causes the `ng-model` directive to register twice - under the same name - with the parent form controller, and long story short, causes some weirdness.

The proper way to deal with contents is by using the `transclude` function, provided to the `link` function of the directive.

```
transclude: true,
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
   transclude(scope, function(clone){
     element.append(clone); // clone is the clone of the contents, prebound to scope
   }
}
```

or, simply, with `<div ng-transclude></div>` via the template, since you don't need to do anything special there

```
transclude: true,
template: '<div ng-transclude></div>`
```

But you don't even need to do any of this, since your directive just puts some classes on the contents and applies some classes to itself, which you are trying to do with `ng-class`, which requires you to use `$compile`. Instead of doing this, simply $watch for changes and apply a class directly:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl){
  var inputName = setupDom(element[0]);

  scope.$watch(function(){
    return formCtrl[inputName].$valid && formCtrl[inputName].$dirty;
  }, function(v){
    if (v) element.addClass("has-success");
    else element.removeClass("has-success");
  });

  scope.$watch(function(){
    return formCtrl[inputName].$invalid && 
           (formCtrl[inputName].$dirty || formCtrl.$submitted);
  }, function(v){
    if (v) element.addClass("has-error");
    else element.removeClass("has-error");
  })
}
```

And there is no need for `$compile` or `transclude`

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yv49vpYpu1VXsNEaYFXH?p=preview)